Anacron job not running
I'm learning to use anacron and scheduled a simple task to be executed everyday
1   6   buendia     /home/ash/Escritorio/saludar.sh

It's a simple script that writes have a good day everyday in a text file(the script by itselfs works alright) but the job doesn't start unless forced with -f.
This is what the logs say:
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Run anacron jobs being skipped.
CRON[3394]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Run anacron jobs being skipped.
systemd[1]: Started Trigger anacron every hour.
systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Run anacron jobs being skipped.

I don't know what it means by "condition check"

What is your Ubuntu version? you mention "the job doesn't start unless forced with -f" - what exactly are the command(s) you are using? The "condition check" here is [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ] which basically checks whether your system uses systemd

Please read the info in this link and edit the question. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
